# How to shrink Text Labels and add attributes to hover info-window in D3 bubble chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How would I be able to shrink or clip text labels so very long id's are not larger then the bubbles in my chart?

Additionally, how do I add additional attributes from my csv to show within the info window when hovering over the bubble? I was assuming this was done in the line of code below, however, it returns as undefined when I run it. I want to add attributes for Author and Genre.

```
node.append("title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.id + "\n" + "Pages: " +format(d.value); });
});
```

Here is my plunker for the full code: https://plnkr.co/edit/nWPuZgZaomSSKSuY6sNB?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is part of the answer, your Genre and Author fields are tucked away under data.

```
return d.id + "\n" + "Pages: " + format(d.value) + "\n" +
"Author: " + d.data.Author + "\n" + "Genre: " + d.data.Genre;
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/lEHToojJ8YzUoVSxE7cr?p=preview

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I was trying to call it as d.Author but didn't realise I needed d.data. Thanks so much for that!

Comment: @HowardSmith Glad to help :-). Regarding the first part, managing word wrap in SVG is not as straight-forward as it should be. This add-on to D3 might help: [link](https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Text-Wrapping/)